# Find the value of theta.

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $X$ have the density function $f(x) = \dfrac{3x^2}{\theta^3}$ for $0 < x < \theta$, and $f(x) = 0$ otherwise. If $P\{X > 1\} = 7/8$, find the value of $\theta$.

I don't know

Comment: What is it that you don't know? The source of the problem? The reason for being interested in it? Any formulas at all relating densities to probabilities?

Answer (score 1):

We know that $\Pr(X\le 1)=\dfrac{1}{8}$. But
$$\Pr(X\le 1)=\int_0^1 \frac{3x^2}{\theta^3}\,dx,$$
which is $\dfrac{1}{\theta^3}$.  Thus we need to solve the equation $\dfrac{1}{\theta^3}=\dfrac{1}{8}$.

**Remark:** Alternately, we could have used the equation
$$\int_1^\theta \frac{2x^2}{\theta^3}\,=\frac{7}{8}.$$
The integral turns out to be $1-\dfrac{1}{\theta^3}$, so we solve $1-\dfrac{1}{\theta^3}=\dfrac{7}{8}$.

Answer (score 0):

You have that $\mathbb{P}\{X>1\}=\frac{7}{8}$ implies $\int_1^{\theta}f(x)dx=\int_1^{\theta}\frac{3x^2}{\theta^3}dx=\frac{1}{\theta^3}\int_1^{\theta}3x^2dx=1-\frac{1}{\theta^3}=\frac{7}{8}$. Hence $\theta=2$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: We have  $\theta > 1$. (Why?). We have $P(X > 1)= \int_1^{+\infty} f(x) dx = \int_1^{\theta} f(x) dx=\frac{3}{\theta^3} \int_1^{\theta} x^2 dx$ gives $\theta=2$.